# Use duplicated values to increment column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe and I want to increment a column based on the amount of duplicated values. So when a duplicate is found, all other occurrences is incremented. So given this input dataframe

```
    SM
 0  AB
 1  AC
 2  AD
 3  AB
 4  AB
 5  AC
 6  AE
 7  AD
```

return

```
     SM DM
  0  AB AB
  1  AC AC
  2  AD AD
  3  AB AB_1
  4  AB AB_2
  5  AC AC_1
  6  AE AE
  7  AD AD_1
```

I tried this line of code but I don't know how to increment

```
 np.where(a.SM.duplicated(keep='first'), a.SM+'_1', a.SM)
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and explain in more detail what the problem was.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dataframe"? Is it a CSV file? Or a NumPy array? Or a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: What exactly do you intend to achieve? Do you just want to count the occurrences of a given value? Do you consider the index of the n'th occurrence important? Is it really necessary to add a string to the end of the occurrence or do you just want to know how many there are or would it be better to have a new column that contains how often the value has been encountered previously? Please state your goal more specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
s = df.groupby('SM').cumcount()

df['DM'] = df['SM'].where(s.eq(0), df['SM'] + '_' + s.astype(str))
```

[out]

```
   SM    DM
0  AB    AB
1  AC    AC
2  AD    AD
3  AB  AB_1
4  AB  AB_2
5  AC  AC_1
6  AE    AE
7  AD  AD_1
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a counter-1 by group in `dplyr` and then `paste()` can provide you with the wanted result:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
# Getting those whose value which Are repeated
df$BoolDup<-duplicated(df$SM)
# Creating counting variable and a second counter that keeps track of the repetitions-1 to then Join if duplicated
df %>% mutate(count = 1) %>% 
  group_by(SM)%>%
  mutate(count2 = cumsum(count)-1) %>%
  mutate(DM = ifelse(BoolDup==TRUE,paste(SM,"_",count2,sep =""), SM))%>%
  dplyr::select(SM=SM, DM=DM)

# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   SM [4]
# SM    DM   
# <chr> <chr>
# 1 AB    AB   
# 2 AC    AC   
# 3 AD    AD   
# 4 AB    AB_1 
# 5 AB    AB_2 
# 6 AC    AC_1 
# 7 AE    AE   
# 8 AD    AD_1
```